# Performance DbContext Linq Query versus ObjectContext Linq Query

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I just had a look at Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 5:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

In 6.7 a graph it shown that states that the performance of a ObjectContext Linq Query is better than DbContext Linq Query. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that DBContext internally uses ObjectContext (ie dbcontext is a wrapper) and therefore wont be faster.

What you may find is that DBContext will out of the box tweek the ObjectContext a little more than prehaps you would using it everyday. For example EF5 does some additional work with compiled queries to allow for a bit better performance. This means that your un-optimised app may perform faster with DBContext (but this is obviously highly dependent on what you are doing). DBContext also adds a lot of simplicity to your application as its a far less complicated interface than OC.

Comment: Auto compilation magic in EF5 happens on ObjectContex level actually

Comment: @pawel yeah thats right, my point was that you dont need to configure it manually, so you get the benefits of compiled queries without having to set them up yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your responses but I'm still confused. I still don't understand why the graph shows that it is slower.